# ExternalName for S3 endpoint in Kubernetes with AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I'm trying to use the AWS S3 SDK for Java to connect to a bucket from a Kubernetes pod running an Spring Boot application. In order to get external access I had to create a service as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: s3
  namespace: production
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

And then I modified my configuration in `application.properties` specifying the endpoint:

```
cloud.aws.endpoint=s3
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=ASD
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=123
cloud.aws.credentials.instanceProfile=true
cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain=true
```

Because the SDK builds the host name for the bucket as `bucket.s3...` I modified my client to use "path style" access with this configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "amazonS3")
public AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
        RegionProvider regionProvider) {

    EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(
            endpoint, regionProvider.getRegion().getName());

    return (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                                .build();
}
```

But when I try to perform any bucket operation I get the following error regarding the name mismatch with the SSL certificate:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <s3> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com, nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com]
```

How can I avoid this certificate error?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue. I believe AmazonS3Client API doesn't resolve the k8s service name. I had to directly use a host name instead of K8s service name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).